# C++. .so and .h usage. What parameters 'main' want?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, md5, header-files, program-entry-point

I have compiled .so library and copied it into my new project. I also copied .h file from source folder.

Now I trying to use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "md5.h"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
md5_init();
md5_append();
md5_finish();
return 0;
}
```

At the output I got an error: too few arguments to function «void md5_init(md5_state_t*)»

And .h file:

```
typedef unsigned char md5_byte_t; /* 8-bit byte */
typedef unsigned int md5_word_t; /* 32-bit word */

/* Define the state of the MD5 Algorithm. */
typedef struct md5_state_s {
    md5_word_t count[2];    /* message length in bits, lsw first */
    md5_word_t abcd[4]; /* digest buffer */
    md5_byte_t buf[64]; /* accumulate block */
} md5_state_t;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

/* Initialize the algorithm. */

#ifdef WIN32
_declspec(dllexport)
#endif
void md5_init(md5_state_t *pms);

/* Append a string to the message. */
#ifdef WIN32
_declspec(dllexport)
#endif
void md5_append(md5_state_t *pms, const md5_byte_t *data, int nbytes);

/* Finish the message and return the digest. */
#ifdef WIN32
_declspec(dllexport)
#endif
void md5_finish(md5_state_t *pms, md5_byte_t digest[16]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* end extern "C" */
#endif
```

Library has obtained frome this [site](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~mabzug1/cs/md5/md5.html). See C++ implementation.

What I misunderstood?

Comment: Have you read the documentation, headers and examples at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MD5 functions that you're calling all require (at least) a structure capable of storing the current state of the "message digesting stream" (the sequence of bytes that you want to generate a digest for).

The structure allows you to store state in between multiple calls to `md5_append()` as well as run *multiple* streams side by side, as the state for a given stream is stored entirely in the structure.

To do that correctly, you need something like:

```
#define HELLO "Hello"
#define SENDR " from Pax"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    md5_state_t pms;
    md5_byte_t digest[16];

    md5_init (&pms);

    md5_append (&pms, (const md5_byte_t *)HELLO, strlen (HELLO));
    md5_append (&pms, (const md5_byte_t *)SENDR, strlen (SENDR));

    md5_finish (&pms, digest);

    // digest now holds the message digest for the given string.

    return 0;
}
```